# Regular expression to only return letters

Tags: php, javascript, regex, delphi, delphi-7

I need to be able to do this in Code Gear or Delphi 7.

I need  a regex pattern. I need a regular expression that chooses ONLY A WORDS, for example I have strings like this:

```
@first
22Second
+Third
_!293-four
{SPACE}five
4_ 42~1!Six
```

And I need to return only a word with normal letters, not symbols or numbers at the start of the string, like (;3,-+!?..@0-9).

Can I get a regex to just match letters?

Answer (score 2):

When you say "ONLY A WORD SYMBOLS" do you mean letters only?

The regex `^[a-zA-Z]+$` would do you then. But none of the words in your example would match.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not fully sure I understood that, but for Delphi 7 there's free [TRegExpr library](http://regexpstudio.com/TRegExpr/TRegExpr.html) that I've found to be nice provider of regular expressions.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question asked (it asked about a regex, not a regex library; the poster apparently already has that). This is at best a comment to the original question, but it's really not even that as it's totally off the subject.

Comment: @KenWhite you did notice the question was asked, and my answer placed, in january? it wasn't clear at all then what the OP wanted - it was rewritten to its current form, where it actually seems understandable that OP is asking for a regular expression, just 21 hours ago.

Comment: Yes, I looked at it in pre-edited form, and it still clearly says the poster is looking for a regex, not a regex library. The changes made 21 hours ago improved some phrasing, but not the actual content of the question. :-)